# Raspberry Pi blocked IP Address over SSH

Tags: ssh

I am new to Raspberry Pi.

I am trying to access my RPi over intranet using Google Secure Shell, but I guess I am blocked. When I tried to access the RPi from my friend's system it allowed me.

It shows following error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
74:30:dc:00:81:a5:2e:f6:7f:16:6a:4d:14:ce:95:5d.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /.ssh/known_hosts:2
ECDSA host key for 192.168.1.1 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
NaCl plugin exited with status code 255.
(R)econnect, (C)hoose another connection, or E(x)it?
```

What should I do. I searched over internet and they suggested me to delete the
`.ssh/known_hosts` file. but I am not able to find that also.

There is no such files in my `home` directory.

Please help me. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR solution to your exact problem:** type this into a Chrome javascript console: `term_.command.removeKnownHostByIndex(2)`

I assume [this is what you term the "google secure shell"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/details?hl=en)? If so, it has [a mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-hterm), a few comments [point to a faq entry on clearing known hosts](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/platform/assets.git;a=blob;f=chromeapps/nassh/doc/faq.txt#l459), and [a user even suggests a quick javascript bookmarklet](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-hterm/Kh-KBZzA8io/ysfeJ_WHlS8J).

**Be very careful and think about why you are removing an entry from the known_hosts file.** It generally indicates you are connecting to a different machine than you expect. That might be due to a reinstall of the operating system or it could be something like a [man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: I guess you dint read the question correctly, I am not able to find the **known_hosts** file too. That is not present

Comment: You need to read the link @tedder42 provided for the FAQ on how to clear known hosts ... the link is http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/platform/assets.git;a=blob;f=chromeapps/nassh/doc/faq.txt#l459

Comment: thanks @HeatfanJohn- I put the exact command to run at the top of the answer.